# Enviando os dados de um form por duas páginas

Tags: php

Bom dia!
Estou com uma dúvida, eu estou enviando os dados de um formulário para um Controller que envia um email com tais dados.
Todavia o Controller ao montar o email usa tal função

```
$body_message = file_get_contents('/email.php');
```

O Modelo do email é muito grande e por isso puxo ele de outro local, todavia eu quero inserir variáveis enviadas pelo formulário no modelo também, como posso fazer isso?
Eu quero que os dados do formulário sejam enviados tanto para a controller quanto para o modelo do email.

Arquivo do ContatoControl.php:

```
        public function enviarEmail(){
        $dados = array();

        $emailClasse = new Email();

        if(isset($_POST['modulo']) && $_POST['modulo'] == "contato"){

            $nomeCompleto  = $_POST['nome'];
            $telefone      = $_POST['telefone'];
            $empresa       = !empty($_POST['empresa'])  ? $_POST['empresa'] : " Não informado.";
            $cargo         = !empty($_POST['cargo'])   ? $_POST['cargo'] : " Não informado.";
            $email         = $_POST['email_corporativo'];    
            $mensagem      = $_POST['mensagem'];

    $arr = array(
        'properties' => array(
            array(
                'property' => 'firstname',
                'value' => $nomeCompleto
            ),
            array(
                'property' => 'email',
                'value' => $email
            ),
            array(
                'property' => 'phone',
                'value' => $telefone
            ),
            array(
                'property' => 'company',
                'value' => $empresa
            )
        )
    );
    $post_json = json_encode($arr);
    $hapikey = ("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX");
    $endpoint = 'https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact?hapikey=' . $hapikey;
    $ch = @curl_init();
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_json);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = @curl_exec($ch);
    $status_code = @curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $curl_errors = curl_error($ch);
    @curl_close($ch);

    $subject = " xxxx- Contato ";
    $body_message = file_get_contents('/email.html');
    $headers = 'De: '.$email."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n";

    $mail_status = mail('xxxx@xxx.com',$subject,$body_message,$headers);

            if($respostaEnvio){
                $dados['mensagem'] = "Contato enviado com sucesso. Aguarde que logo te enviaremos uma resposta.";
            }else{
                $dados['mensagem'] = "Não foi possível enviar a mensagem no momento. Tente mais tarde.";
            }

        }
```

O Código do email esta no link abaixo do pastebin pois não cabia na pergunta:
https://pastebin.com/FtjpctfH

Comment: Você quer que dados do formulário sejam inseridos no corpo do email?

Comment: Oi Whatyson, sim

Comment: poderia colocar o conteúdo do e-mail?

Comment: Oi Marcus, o conteúdo do email bem como o controller estão ai na pergunta, editei e adicionei eles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode construir uma função para bindar os dados que você pretende substituir, por exemplo, constroe uma array (que você já tem) com os dados que você quer substituir e os respectivos valores:

```
$args = [
    ":nomeCompleto:" => $nomeCompleto,
    ":telefone:" => $telefone,
    ":empresa:" => $empresa,
    ":cargo:" => $cargo,
    ":email:" => $email,
    ":mensagem:" => $mensagem,
]
```

E a função pode ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
function bind($str, $args) {
    foreach($args as $key => $arg) {
        $str = str_ireplace($key, $arg, $str);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Daí basta você bindar o texto antes de enviar o email:

```
$body_message = bind($body_message, $args);
```

Ou seja, a função vai pegar sua string (no caso, o **$body_message**) e substituir os dados *:variavel:* pelo valor que vier do formulário.

Comment: Muuuuuito obrigado Whatyson! me ajudou de mais!!!

Comment: Por nada @CaueSilvestre , atente-se que se houver qualquer dado no corpo do email que seja igual ao :key: na sua array ele também será substituido, ou seja, revise o corpo do email e as chaves que você está usando na sua array.